# Can I import two underscore variable from another file?

Tags: python

abc1234.py

```
__foo__ = "bar"
```

test1234.py

```
import abc1234
print abc1234._abc1234__foo__
```

it doesn't work. How to fix it ?

Comment: Can you see the attribute you want when you print `dir(abc1234)`?

Comment: Just `print abc1234.__foo__`

Answer (score 2):

First point: name mangling is only invoked for classes, not for modules.

Second point: it's only invoked for names with 2 leading underscores and NO trailing underscores - double-double-underscores names (ak `__magic__` names) are reserved for implementation.

Also there are actually very few real use cases for name-mangling, so better to stick with the single-leading-underscore convention (python's equivalent of "protected") for "not public" names.

Comment: Reference for [not defining your own dunder names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers).

Comment: @chepner thanks - I actually meant to look for it and edit my answer and I totally forgot xD